# How to show that the low energy effective bosonic sigma model is consistent : $\beta^G=\beta^B=0 \Rightarrow \beta^\phi=cnst$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, string-theory, renormalization

I am totally stuck at an exercise regarding the consistency of nonlinear sigma model...

Let
\begin{equation}
\beta^G_{ab}=R_{ab}+2D_a D_b \phi-\frac{1}{4}H_{acd}H^{bcd}\text{, }\beta^H_{ab}=-\frac{1}{2}D^c H_{cab}+D^c\phi H_{cab}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\beta^\phi=\frac{D-26}{6}+\alpha(-\frac{1}{2}D^2 \phi+D_c \phi D^c \phi -\frac{1}{24}H_{abc}H^{abc})
\end{equation}

where $\phi$ is a scalar field, $B_{ab}$ is an antisymmetric tensor field such that $H_{abc}=\partial_a B_{bc}+\partial_b B_{ca}+\partial_c B_{ab}$, and we are assuming a curved background spacetime. This means that $G$ is a metric field, $R_{ab}$ is the Ricci curvature, and $D$ is the covariant derivative.

I want to show that  $\beta^G_{ab}=\beta^B_{ab}=0$ implies $\beta^\phi=cnst$. I am given the following hints:

\begin{equation}
2D^a R_{ab}=\partial_b R \text{, } H_{abc} D^a H^{fbc}=\frac{1}{6}D^f H^2
\end{equation}

However, I cannot find a way to show that the covariant derivatives of $\beta^\phi$ vanish... How can one perform such 'magic' manipulation??

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Could you perhaps explain your notation? Or perhaps what source you are using? None of it looks like any other verisons  of the non-linear sigma mode that I am familiar with.  What is your target space?

Comment: https://courses-archive.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/54339

Comment: This is one of the sources from which I got this problem. In the link above, the problem is 1-(2).

Comment: Ah... it's string theory ---  not a sigma model in the usual sense. The problems sheet has too many undefined terms for me to say anythiong useful